# Yet another group of five sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

This is my third batch of sequence puzzles that are nasty and hard to solve; 
yet, each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

---

> Sequence 1:
>   2, 4, 4, 3, ?, ?, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, ?, ?, ...

---

> Sequence 2:
>   ?, ?, ?, J, J, ?, A, M, ?, J, J, Z, M, F, J, A, A, U, R, J, C, G, B, G, W, T, W, W, W, ...

---

> Sequence 3:
>   ??, ??, Ca, Cl, Ne, Ga, ??, ??, ??, Ti, ??, Ne, ??, ??, ??, Au, Lu, ...

---

> Sequence 4:
>   0.06, 0.82, 1.00, 0.11, ??, ??, 14.6, 17.2

---

> Sequence 5:
>   A, E, A, P, A, ?, U, ?, E, ?, ?, ...

Comment: Since sequence 5 has been solved last, I count it as the most difficult one of the five sequences and I assign the "correct answer" sign to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequence 5 is:

> A, E, A, P, A, **U**, U, **U**, **E**, **C**, **O**, **E**

Why?

> Second letter of the month:
> J**a**nuary
> F**e**bruary
> M**a**rch
> A**p**ril
> M**a**y
> J**u**ne
> J**u**ly
> A**u**gust
> S**e**ptember
> O**c**tober
> N**o**vember
> D**e**cember

Note:

> Well done to OP for not listing twelve items as that would have taken 5 seconds :D

**I'm not going to mention the other sequences as they are already answered by others:**

- [Sequence 1 and 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/8693/5610)
- [Sequence 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/8608/5610)
- [Sequence 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/8606/5610)

Answer (score 8):

Sequence 2:

> First initials of US Presidents, in order of when they were in office. **G**eorge Washington, **J**ohn Adams, **T**homas Jefferson, **J**ames Madison, **J**ames Monroe, **J**ohn Quincy Adams, **A**ndrew Jackson, **M**artin Van Buren, **W**illiam Henry Harrison, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I could google sequence 4:

Sequence 4:

> "The Evolving Universe and the Origin of Life: The Search for Our Cosmic Roots"
>  Mass of the planets in our solar system measured relative to Earth
> I have googled0.06 0.82 1.00 0.11 317.9 95.2 14.6 17.2

Answer (score 6):

Sequence 1 is a list of:

> [Morse code dots+dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) for letters A through T (missing numbers are in **bold**):
>  2, 4, 4, 3, **1, 4**, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, **3, 1**, . .

Sequence 3 is a list of:

> [Roman emperors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Roman_emperors) (missing names in **bold**):
>  **Augustus, Tiberius**, Caligula, Claudius, Nero, Galba, **Otho, Vitellius, Vespasian**, Titus, **Domitian**, Nerva, **Trajan, Hadrian, Antoninus Pius**, Marcus Aurelius, Lucius Verus, . . .